# Can "so" in the following "did so" be omitted?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I left the teachers' lounge, one of the few times I did **(so)** with a smile on my face. [Explanation: students rarely leave the teachers' lounge smiling.]

Can **so** be omitted? If not, can **so** be replaced by something else?

Comment: You could say _did it_ or _did that_ (but _did so_ sounds better). I think the sentence would be awkward without something after _did_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there probably are contexts in which omitting ***so*** after the verb ***to do*** reads unnaturally, but in this instance:

> I left the teachers' lounge - one of the few times I *did* with a smile on my face.

seems natural enough.

(**N.B.** Note the stress on ***did***.)

---

To be honest though, I feel that **past perfect** feels more natural in this sentence, where both:

> I left the teachers' lounge - one of the few times I had done so with a smile on my face.

and

> I left the teachers' lounge - one of the few times I *had* done with a smile on my face.

sound (to me) completely natural.

(**N.B.** Again, note the stress on ***had***.)